# swt layout suggestion

Tags: java, layout, swt

I need one layout where 2 compsites can sit together VERTICALLY.
The first composite should have a bigger height than the second. I can't use null layout. I have to use some layout manager for this. 
Whenever I resize the shell, the composites should resize also. Which layout can manage this? Please see the attached screenshot. This is the kind of output that I need.![CAn anybody see the image which I have attached here? I am not able to see.

[image: below the screen shot of the layout screen]

I dont know why screen shot is not appearing. I have added the code below. Please try.

```
package views;

import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;


public class NewComposite extends org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite {
    private Composite composite1;
    private Composite composite2;

    /**
    * Auto-generated main method to display this 
    * org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite inside a new Shell.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showGUI();
    }

    /**
    * Overriding checkSubclass allows this class to extend org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite
    */  
    protected void checkSubclass() {
    }

    /**
    * Auto-generated method to display this 
    * org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite inside a new Shell.
    */
    public static void showGUI() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        NewComposite inst = new NewComposite(shell, SWT.NULL);
        Point size = inst.getSize();
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.layout();
        if(size.x == 0 && size.y == 0) {
            inst.pack();
            shell.pack();
        } else {
            Rectangle shellBounds = shell.computeTrim(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
            shell.setSize(shellBounds.width, shellBounds.height);
        }
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }

    public NewComposite(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            this.setLayout(null);
            this.setSize(492, 304);
            {
                composite1 = new Composite(this, SWT.BORDER_SOLID);
                GridLayout composite1Layout = new GridLayout();
                composite1Layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
                composite1.setLayout(composite1Layout);
                composite1.setBounds(0, 0, 492, 232);
                composite1.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));

            }
            {
                composite2 = new Composite(this, SWT.BORDER_SOLID);
                GridLayout composite2Layout = new GridLayout();
                composite2Layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
                composite2.setLayout(composite2Layout);
                composite2.setBounds(0, 232, 492, 72);
                composite2.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
            }
            this.layout();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why the first-choice layout manager, `GridLayout`, shouldn't be able to handle this.

Comment: @Ameoo yes I am using eclipse.@MarkoTopolnik why I am using layout manager is while resizing the composits hs to fit in the screen. If I dont use any layout manager,then while resizing, other other empty parts will be seen. Please make my correct if I am wrong.

Comment: you can add an event listener to the window and you can modify the other components' size when such a window resize event occurs. If you're using eclipse, I suggest installing windowbuilder for a wysiwyg designer and you could go from there.

Comment: Ya I have used one Jigloo wysiwyg design and code I have entered. Please have a look. When resizing it is not fitting to the screen.

Comment: No, I asked why **don't you** use `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using layout managers wrong -- you are setting `GridLayout` to each of the child composites (`composite1`, `composite2`) but you are setting a `null` layout to their parent (`this`). It is the parent component that manages the size and placement of its children. So set `GridLayout` to `this` and set `layoutData` of each child to the appropriately configured `GridData`. How to configure those, see Javadoc. It involves setting `grabExcessVerticalSpace` and using `SWT.FILL` for `verticalAlignment`.

Comment: OK.Thanks a lot Marko Topolink. I will follow in that way.